# Always define standard rule '@keyframes' when defining keyframes

Tags: css, css3

Tenho um css com a seguinte animação:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -ms-transform: translateY(0); }
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -o-transform: translateY(0); }
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
```

Mas o VS Code deixa uma mensagem de erro:

> Always define standard rule '@keyframes' when defining keyframes.

Não consigo resolver. Alguém conhece e poderia me ajudar com isso por favor?

Comment: Tu definiu como `@-webkit-keyframes`, ele tá reclamando disso, tenta colocar só `@keyframes`

Answer (score 3):

Vc declarou errado, vc usou um monte de `vendor prefix` tudo dentro do `-webkit-` isso não pode... vc tem que declarar de forma separada!

Isso é errado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O jeito correto seria assim, veja que não tem alerta nenhum de erro!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
@-ms-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -ms-transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { -ms-transform: translateY(-20px); }
    80% { -ms-transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -o-transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { -o-transform: translateY(-20px); }
    80% { -o-transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px); }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { -moz-transform: translateY(-20px); }
    80% { -moz-transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { transform: translateY(0); }
    40%  { transform: translateY(-20px); }
    80% { transform: translateY(-10px); }
}
```